# How to effectively determine the maximum difference between the variable value in each row and same variable subsequent row values in data.table in R

Tags: r, algorithm, dplyr, data.table

What is the most efficient way to determine the maximum positive difference between the value (X) for each row and the subsequent values of the same variable (X) within group (Y) in data.table in R.

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(X = sample(100:200, 500455, replace = TRUE),
                 Y = unlist(sapply(10:1000, function(x) rep(x, x))))
```

Here's my solution which I consider ineffective and slow:

```
dt[, max_diff := vapply(1:.N, function(x) max(X[x:.N] - X[x]), numeric(1)), by = Y]
head(dt, 21)

      X  Y max_diff
 1: 126 10      69
 2: 137 10      58
 3: 157 10      38
 4: 191 10       4
 5: 120 10      75
 6: 190 10       5
 7: 195 10       0
 8: 166 10       0
 9: 163 10       0
10: 106 10       0
11: 120 11      80
12: 117 11      83
13: 169 11      31
14: 138 11      62
15: 177 11      23
16: 150 11      50
17: 172 11      28
18: 200 11       0
19: 138 11      56
20: 178 11      16
21: 194 11       0
```

If you can advise the efficient (faster) solution?

Comment: I'm a data.table beginner, but I suspect it would be quicker to reverse the ordering within each group Y, record the cumulative max, and then take the difference between that max and X (limiting to zero in case no larger #s remain). The largest difference will always be found against the largest remaining number in the group, so you don't need to check the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a dplyr solution that is about 20x faster and gets the same results. I presume the data.table equivalent would be yet faster. (EDIT: see bottom - it is!)

The speedup comes from reducing how many comparisons need to be performed. The largest difference will always be found against the largest remaining number in the group, so it's faster to identify that number first and do only the one subtraction per row.

First, the original solution takes about 4 sec on my machine:

```
tictoc::tic("OP data.table") 
dt[, max_diff := vapply(1:.N, function(x) max(X[x:.N] - X[x]), numeric(1)), by = Y]
tictoc::toc()
# OP data.table: 4.594 sec elapsed
```

But in only 0.2 sec we can take that data.table, convert to a data frame, add the `orig_row` row number, group by Y, reverse sort by `orig_row`, take the difference between X and the cumulative max of X, ungroup, and rearrange in original order:

```
library(dplyr)
tictoc::tic("dplyr") 
dt2 <- dt %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>%
  mutate(orig_row = row_number()) %>%

  group_by(Y) %>%
  arrange(-orig_row) %>%
  mutate(max_diff2 = cummax(X) - X) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(orig_row)
tictoc::toc()
# dplyr: 0.166 sec elapsed

all.equal(dt2$max_diff, dt2$max_diff2)
#[1] TRUE
```

EDIT: as @david-arenburg suggests in the comments, this can be done lightning-fast in data.table with an elegant line:

```
dt[.N:1, max_diff2 := cummax(X) - X, by = Y]
```

On my computer, that's about 2-4x faster than the `dplyr` solution above.

Comment: Splendid. That's another 2-4x faster.

Comment: My mistake. Thanks -- I need to spend more time with data.table.

Comment: @JonSpring Thank You, Jon! Your solution is very smart and amazingly fast!

Comment: @DavidArenburg David, thank you for converting it in even faster and elegant data.table format.

Comment: Now it's ~ x100 faster than my initial approach!